# How to handle multiple conditions with @If using new v17 syntax and async pipe

Tags: angular, angular17

I'm trying to use the the new angular syntax for the old ***ngIf**. In my template I would like to combine the following to **@if** statements

```
@if(foo.bar$ | async;as bar) {
     <h2>{{bar}}</h2>
}
```

and

```
@if((foo.bar$ | async) !== 'yolo') {
    
}
```

Those work. Ideally I would like to combine them, something like

```
@if(foo.bar$ | async;as bar !== 'yolo') {
    <h2>{{bar}}</h2>
}
```

or

```
@if((foo.bar$ | async;as bar) && bar !== 'yolo') {
    <h2>{{bar}}</h2>
}
```

I can try more, but the point is, this is incorrect syntax. So my question is, is something like this possible or should I just have 2 **@if** statements?

Comment: Perhaps this post can help you. It's related to the old syntax, but I think it still applies to the new syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296784/angular-ngif-variable-with-async-pipe-multiple-conditions

Comment: Yes, that seems to work as: `(foo.bar$ | async) !== 'yolo' && (foo.bar$ | async); as bar`. Its using `async` twice, not ideal, but if this is it, this is it :) Thnx!!